# undefined variable jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, undefined

I don't understand how to pass a variable from the init function to the bindEvent function in my object:
At the moment, I get undefined.

```
var Fisheye = {
    init: function () {

        $('body').hide();

        $(window).load(function() {
            $('body').fadeIn('slow');

            this.imgs = $('.pic').children('img');
            this.originalWidth = $(imgs).first().css('width');
            this.minWidth = 300;

            imgs.width(300);

            Fisheye.bindEvents();

        });

    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        $(this.imgs).toggle(this.toggleClick, this.toggleClick);
        console.log(this.imgs); // Why do I get Undefined here?
    },

    toggleClick: function() {
        //Todo
    }
}


Fisheye.init();
```

How to properly pass a variable from a function to another in an object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var Fisheye = {

    init: function () {
        var _this = this;
        $('body').hide();
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('body').fadeIn('slow');
            _this.imgs = $('.pic').children('img');
            _this.originalWidth = $(_this.imgs).first().css('width');
            _this.minWidth = 300;
            _this.imgs.width(300);
            _this.bindEvents();
        });

    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        $(this.imgs).toggle(this.toggleClick, this.toggleClick);
    },

    toggleClick: function() {
        //Todo
    }
}


Fisheye.init();
```

The problem is that the "this" in you handler wasn't the instance of Fisheye but the window.

But you'll have a similar problem with the toggleClick. A solution for those could be to do this :

```
bindEvents: function() {
    var _this = this;
    var toggleFunction = function(){_this.toggleClick()};
    $(this.imgs).toggle(toggleFunction, toggleFunction);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

rapidly just the structure , add param to the function

```
 bindEvents: function(imgs) {
    $(imgs).toggle(this.toggleClick, this.toggleClick);
    console.log(imgs); // Why do I get Undefined here?
},...
```

on init function

```
...
var imgs = ..
Fisheye.bindEvents(imgs);
```